# Postgres Heroku Connection limit details - Rails application - ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am working on the free and fair use of Heroku for a Rails Postgres application.
Regarding the pricing on Heroku Postgres, I can see a connection limit (set to 120 for the cheapest offer).

What does this connection limit mean?
I have seen it which may deal with the parameter max_connections but even that, I do not really get how it works.

If I have my rails server receiving an order and request my database for an update or simple select with always the same database Postgres user: does it count for one connection?
I do not think so but I would like to get more details on this limit.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_connection` defines the number of Postgres instances running simultaneously to serve queries. `max_connections` open up multiple connection for same postgres user. It can increase performance in some cases but this can lead to poor performance like these:

- **Disk contention**: If you are using disk(not RAM) then more tables and indexes to be accessed at the same time, causing heavier seeking all over the disk
- **RAM**: This leads more RAM usage.
- **Synchronization**: You need to handle synchronization of multiple instances which will effect the overall throughput.

If you are user base increases, then you may face `too many clients` error due to limited number of connections. Then there is a concept of

The solution is to two fold:

- **pool connections**: If Postgres is failing to handle the situation, you can use tools like `pgbouncer, repmgr and PgPool` to handle pool connection before going to Postgres.
- **Application optimization**: Try to open as less connections as possible and close the connection as soon as work is done.

You can study further on this from following links:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS

You can study particularly for Ruby here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#maximum-database-connections